# unique type identifiers across different C++ programs

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Is there a way to automatically (i.e. not by hand) assign unique identifiers to types in different programs that share common source code?  I'd need one program to tell another "use type X" and the other would know what that "X" meant.  Of course, they would (partially) share the source code, as you cannot construct types in runtime, I just want an automatic way of constructing a map from some sort of identifiers (integers or strings) to e.g. factory functions returning objects of given type.

An obvious choice I'd go for is result of `name()` in `std::type_info`, but as I understand, that is not even guaranteed to be different across types, and using address of `std::type_info` instances is certainly not going to work across programs.

I cannot use C++11, but can use Boost for this.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that works across platforms, or would something specific to GNU or to Windows be acceptable in your case?

Comment: Is the aim to send data of these types from one program to another?  If so, then you need to think about the entire serialisation/deserialisation problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: No, I need something cross-platform.  After all, reasonable compilers seem to provide good enough `name()` in `std::type_info`.  If I cannot find a better solution, I will settle for that, at least for a start.

Comment: @Oli: I don't need that, I use Boost.Interprocess to share objects in memory.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want an automatic way of constructing a map from some sort of
>   identifiers (integers or strings) to e.g. factory functions returning
>   objects of given type.

Not going to happen, not within Standard C++, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [boost serialisation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#derivedpointers). It automatically generates unique ids for polimorphic classes and allows the explicit registration of non polimorphic ones.